# Installing ubuntu in dual boot with windows 10 x64

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning

I'm trying to compile github project on windows but i get some problems , so the only solution to solve those errors is to install linux operating beacause this project work only on linux distrubtion ( sorry for my bad language ) .
I have windows 10 x64 and i want to install ubuntu with windows 10 in dual boot, 
So for now there is no problem beacause there is many tutorials describe how to do this , i followed many tutorials but i get some problems in partitions .
As you can see i have this partition , 
+ My pc is lenovo z50-70

[Parition in windows 10 x64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPoTm.png)

I have resized D: i give 30 Go ( unallocated space ) 
but i get this error :

[Error Message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I117B.png)

[Error Message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM65O.png)

So i want to know how can i resize and create volume to allocate space for ubuntu os

Note: I have used two software that allocate paritions but it doesn't help me e.g EaseUS Parition , MiniTool Parition Wizard

Update : [Error english description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTerp.png)

Comment: Actually the good solution in this case may be to install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) in Windows and run a Linux system in a VM (you don't even need to install Linux, you'll find pre-installed Vbox images of most popular Linux distros).

Comment: @xenoid Virtualbox causes problems beacause i need a os system installing and i need to setting graphic card ( Cuda Nvidia ) to compile project on my PC not virtualisation

Comment: @Scott i update my question , you can see the error in english

Comment: Your installation, the current Windows, seems to be in Legacy mode. That implies the old "msdos" partitioning which in turn limits the number of primary partitions to 4. You can't create additional partitions in that dive unless at least one is deleted. Without the possibility of creating at least one (extended) partition - that can contain several logical partitions inside - no other OS can be installed in that drive. Now that you know this please consider your options.

Comment: So according to what you said, it impossible to install ubuntu dual boot with windows ? so if i want to install ubuntu i should change by windows os ?